# jQuery - Can .draggable() stick to browser border?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is draggable. Now, i would like that div to stick to border of browser window. Is this possible? Or maybe there are some extension plugins that can make this happen?

Comment: [`.draggable({containment:"window"});`](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement). If you want it to snap to element, then use [snap](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to)

Comment: Yeah, but it wont stick. :) Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot imitate `window` in jsfiddle's frame, I will use `html` for this example.

Use [`snap`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snap) and [`snapMode`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapMode),

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(selector).draggable({
        snap:"html",
        snapMode: "inner"});
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/38/

Hope this points you in the right direction. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: :D Great, thanks. One more question: Is it possible to make a margin between object and browser border?

Comment: @ojek, sorry not really following, do you mean have it snap close to, but not on, the browser border?